# object in sizers behave unexpecdly

Tags: python, wxpython

I have the following code in Wxpython:

```
    sizer_1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    sizer_2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    sizer_3 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

    self.label_1 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, _("XXX:                   "))
    self.label_2 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, _("XXXXXX (Xxxxxxxx):     "))

    self.t1= wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, "")
    self.t2= wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, "")

    sizer_1.Add(self.label_1, 1, wx.LEFT, 10)
    sizer_1.Add(self.t1, 1, wx.RIGHT, 10)
    sizer_2.Add(self.label_2, 1, wx.LEFT, 10)
    sizer_2.Add(self.t2, 1, wx.RIGHT, 10)


    sizer_3.Add((0, 15), 0, 0, 0)
    sizer_3.Add(sizer_1,0)
    sizer_3.Add((0, 15), 0, 0, 0)
    sizer_3.Add(sizer_2,0)
    sizer_3.Add((0, 15), 0, 0, 0)
```

This gives:

[image]

Why are the textCtrl aren't alligned?

the labels take the same space.. so why the textctrl starts from diffrent locations?

Answer (score 0):

Think of a sizer as a self contained window within a window, because you are assigning each item and its label to a different sizer, they are treated as separate sub-windows.
Add them both into sizer_1 and then put sizer_1 into sizer_3 and they will line up, due to the fact that they are both being controlled by the same sizer (sizer_1).